# Avoiding `String can't be coerced into BigDecimal`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I wrote a logic/method that returns a two different objects (Integer and String), such that for an example the returned value will be `5000.00 Dollars`.

So I wrote a method to for my expectations. See the logic below:

```
s = x.currency # This assigns the string `dollarpounds` to s
a = s.slice(6..11) # This slice off 6 to 11 and returns just pounds to variable a
price_value = x.price # This is integer (price)
volume_volume = x.volume # This is integer (volume)
value = price_value * volume_volume # This multiplies price and volume and returns the value
value + "#{a}" # Now this throws TypeError-String can't be coerced into BigDecimal
```

So to do away with this problem I refactored my method but I think its very insulting snippet to be considered a master in Ruby. *How do I re-write this re-factored logic below to be smart enough as Ruby code?*

**So here is what I have done:**

**Re-factored logic**. It returns `5000.00 Dollars` as expected

```
s = x.currency # This assigns the string `dollarpounds` to s
a = s.slice(6..11) # This slice off 6 to 11 and returns just pounds to variable a
price_value = x.price # This is integer (price)
volume_volume = x.volume # This is integer (volume)
value = price_value * volume_volume # This multiplies price and volume and returns the value
[[value].join(' '), "#{a}"].split(',').join(' ') # This returns 5000.00 Dollars
```

As much my `re-factored` code works, I still feel it's insulting to ruby community and can be better than this. Any help how to do it better will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use interpolation:

```
"#{value} #{a}"
```

Or concatenation:

```
value.to_s + ' ' + a
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite funny how I used interpolation in the last line of the refactor `[[value].join(' '), "#{a}"].split(',').join(' ')` and I never dim it fit to simply use Interpolation. Aside the suggested interpolation by in the answers thread, I was able to make the code more simple, smaller, and faster.

```
s = x.currency
a = s.slice(6..11)
value = x.price * x.volume
"#{value} #{a}" # Thanks to @PavelPuzin for this suggestion in this line.
```

Another thing we can consider about the best way to go about this is to investigate `Interpolation` and the `Join` I used by using Benchmark to determine its Algorithmic Complexity:

```
require "benchmark"

numbers = (1..1000).to_a

n = 1000
Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report { n.times do   ; numbers.each_cons(2) {|a, b| "#{a} #{b}"}; end }
  x.report { n.times do   ; numbers.each_cons(2) {|a, b| [a, b].join(" ")}; end }
end 

###############################Result###################################
    user     system      total        real
   0.467287   0.000731   0.468018 (  0.468641)
   1.154991   0.001563   1.156554 (  1.157740)
```